# Deriving the fundamental equation relationship

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, computer-science

I'm having a hard time understanding how a few equations are being derived. So the fundamental equation is an equation that relates corresponding points in stereo images. Anyway, that's the basic background. The question is more on the matrix manipulation. So I'm trying to get (1) and (2) into (3) and I have

(1) $\tilde m_1 = A_1[I\hspace{5 pt}0]\tilde M $

(2) $\tilde m_2 = A_2[R\hspace{5 pt}t]\tilde M$

Eliminating $M$ from the above equations you can obtain

(3) $\tilde m_2^T \hspace{2 pt} A_2^{-T} \hspace{2 pt} [t]_x\hspace{2 pt} R \hspace{2 pt}A_1^{-1} \tilde m_1 = 0$

And some notes:

a. If $V=[x,y,..]^T$, then $\tilde V = [x,y,..,1]^T$

b. $[t]_x$ is an antisymmetrix (or skew symmetric) matrix such that $[t]_xx = t \times x$ for all vector x

c. $[A\hspace{5 pt}b]$ is a matrix composed of $A$ with vector $b$ as the last column

d. $\tilde m$ is 3x1, $\tilde M$ is 4x1, $A$ is 3x3, and $R$ is 3x3

So far I can get as far as dropping the scalars, then taking $A^{-1}$ of both sides of (1) but beyond that I'm a bit lost...Perhaps if I could get some hints into matrix operations that would be useful or identities that can simplify some of these

Comment: It looks like $t$ is a $3 \times 1$ column vector denoting a translation, but what do you mean by $[t]_x$?

Comment: If you look at d. I shows that that's basically a cross product in matrix form. Any other vector multiplied by that will compute the cross product of the two. And yes, in this case, t is a translation column vector